# Azure ML Workspace is not able to upload data in for workspace linked storage account which is behind VNet

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to setup an Azure ML workspace with Storage Accound behind the Vnet but when trying to upload an sata from Data tab I am getting below error.

[image]

I have all the necessary setting as describe in the below article but still no luck

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-workspace-vnet?tabs=se%2Ccli#secure-the-workspace-with-private-endpoint

Things did to make Storage Accessible to ML workspace

1. Enabled Azure.Storage Service Endpoint from Vnet
2. Done this setting on Storage [image]
3. Both the ML Workspace and Storage are in same subnet
4. Assigned "Storage Blob Data Reader" permission for Worspace
5. Accessing this ML Workspace from Virtual machine created on same subnet.

Can anyone suggest is there anything missing ?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one storage account in which I enabled **Networking** settings as below:

[image]

When I tried to upload data from Azure Machine Learning Studio, I got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add your **client IP address** under storage account's Firewall settings like below:

[image]

Now, I tried to upload data again from Azure Machine Learning Studio and got **results** like below:

[image]

When I selected **Next**, it took me to **`Review`** tab like below:

[image]

After clicking on **Create**, data asset is created successfully with below details:

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where **`test.txt`** file uploaded to storage account successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to add your **client IP address** under storage account's firewall settings. If the error still persists, try with **`Storage Blob Data Contributor`** role.

**Reference:**

[Connect to data storage with the studio UI - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-connect-data-ui?tabs=credential#storage-access-and-permissions)

Comment: Thanks, Sridevi for your answer.  Ideally, the workspace should allow connecting with Azure Backbone Network since I have marked the checkbox as well for "Trusted resources to access this resource". Also, I am accessing this resource from Virtual Network where I have deployed a sample machine for testing workspace and given access to that VNet via Selected Network . Ideally it should allow access within a virtual network

Answer (score 0):

I have created a private endpoint for the storage account in the same subnet of the workspace and it started working.

Still thinking about why with Service Endpoint it's not working. Is there any configurations I am missing.